# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined とjQueryの読み込みについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascriptとjQueryを使ってHPを作成中です。
両言語とも初心者です。
jQueryは2つ以上読み込まない方がいいと言うのもあるみたいですが
今回は[こちら](https://codepen.io/fluxus/pen/gPWvZm)にあるサイトの動きを模倣したいと考えてます。

ソースが載ってるGitHubにはjQueryを以下の通り2つ読み込んでるように思えます。

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://julian.com/research/velocity/build/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
```

複数のjQueryを読み込む場合は `jQuery.noConflict(true)` と言う魔法の言葉あると参考にしたQiitaの記事で言われていたので試してみましたが、動きませんでした。
多分、書き方が悪いのだと思うのですが、、、

[（良くないけど）ページに複数のjQueryを読み込む。 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mijabi/items/c68d27bc2ea5642675af)

/hoge/script.jsをロードしようとすると `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` と言われてしまいます。

どなたか解決策をご存知の方いらっしゃったら、ご教授よろしくお願いします。
まず、jQueryは2つ以上読み込まないと言うお話も

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon_url">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="page.name">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="Summary with Large Image">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./page.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://hoge.jp/hoge/hoge/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  <div class="open-overlay">
    <span class="bar-top"></span>
    <span class="bar-middle"></span>
    <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"　src="http://julian.com/research/velocity/build/jquery.velocity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"　src="http://julian.com/research/velocity/build/velocity.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/hoge/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

/hoge/script.js

```js
$(function(){ ←エラーが発生しているところ。
     $('.open-overlay').click(function() {
       $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
       var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
         top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
         middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
         bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

       overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
       if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

         top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
         middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
         bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
         overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
         overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn', {
           duration: 300,
           delay: 0,
           begin: function() {
             $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveLeftIn', {
               stagger: 150,
               delay: 0,
               complete: function() {
                 $('nav ul li a').velocity({
                   opacity: [1, 0],
                 }, {
                   delay: 10,
                   duration: 140
                 });
                 $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
               }
             })
           }
         })

       } else {
         $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
         top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
         middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
         bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
         overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
         $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveRightOut', {
           stagger: 150,
           delay: 0,
           complete: function() {
             overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.fadeOut', {
               delay: 0,
               duration: 300,
               complete: function() {
                 $('nav ul li a').velocity({
                   opacity: [0, 1],
                 }, {
                   delay: 0,
                   duration: 50
                 });
                 $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
               }
             });
           }
         })
       }
     })
     });
```

Comment: jQuery は詳しくありませんが、`jquery.velocity.min.js` は "velocity.js" と呼ばれるプラグインであって、jQuery を2回読み込んでいるわけではない気がします。

Comment: 私の環境だと`Uncaught ReferenceError`は発生しないようです。質問の編集機能にコードスニペットで記述できる欄がありますのでこちら再現できるソースで記述してみてください。

Comment: keitaro_soさんコードスニペットの書き方がわからないのですが、どこで編集すれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/hoge/script.js"></script>の部分を消して、直接、/hoge/script.jsの内容をhtmlにベタ書きしてみたのですが、同じエラーが発生しました。別のjQueryを読んでいたりすると$functionは読み込まれないと言う話を聞いたことがありますが、今回は2.1.3/jquery.min.jsしか読み込んでいない想定です。何か別の要因でエラーを起こしていると言うことはないでしょうか。

Comment: 読み込みはできるようになりました。これと言って何かをしたわけではないですが。。。新たに問題が発生しております。以下にまとめたので一緒にみていただけると幸いです。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/67677/uncaught-typeerror-overlay-navigation-velocity-is-not-a-function%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6