# Uncaught TypeError: overlay_navigation.velocity is not a functionのエラーについて

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

以下のようにサイトを作成中です。
[サンプル](https://codepen.io/fluxus/pen/gPWvZm?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=6d55cf88a585577dbaa12ba08490e450cc79c7c1-1592207232-0-AXfASKtMs4bt1RJ7cPuIPUWNM9kMfN4QOCN7uBZ5qnHj3rejtFv-ANlCJYySu_I0TZ6GUN_kAcS0NEhYW2hyY9bIYi8f7kqDNvkqTIo-dpAUszQlnr3TgVDLAZuoetBSDK2JTpSKUHvMCsDSpMEyEAK8emW9sLYj7_BIwSFTXYp6InYp8cZcRyKIICIToOGuPVat3WndxaBkZ5QVJI6V-2-rWtjpmCkcdXF-U6G6xuvIbY1UwLQyJZ6KfjgdLZTLAnadb5xqGoFeiaQZzlYm5f7Boin8wDe_02wMMC94gloI8Htj45yCM0z_ch819TXifzlVPuyHNuqTXwKuPMXExvT_FAt1iZlsZ549NEPrM_M1)のように三本バーをクリックするとアクションが行われるようにしたいと考えてます。

jsにある `overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn'` の部分でエラーを起こします。
出ているエラーは以下になります。

```
script.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: overlay_navigation.velocity is not a function
 at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (script.js:16)
 at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
 at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

解決方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらご連絡ください。
よろしくお願いします。

```js
$(function(){
 $('.open-overlay').click(function() {
   $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
   var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
     top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
     middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
     bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

   overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
   if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

     top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
     overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn', {
       duration: 300,
       delay: 0,
       begin: function() {
         $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveLeftIn', {
           stagger: 150,
           delay: 0,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [1, 0],
             }, {
               delay: 10,
               duration: 140
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         })
       }
     })

   } else {
     $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
     top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
     $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveRightOut', {
       stagger: 150,
       delay: 0,
       complete: function() {
         overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.fadeOut', {
           delay: 0,
           duration: 300,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [0, 1],
             }, {
               delay: 0,
               duration: 50
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         });
       }
     })
   }
 })
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gigaplus.makeshop.jp/kukunochi/velocity/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.ui.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  <div class="open-overlay">
<span class="bar-top"></span>
<span class="bar-middle"></span>
<span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: スニペットを実行すると質問とは違うエラーが発生しているようです。再現性が取れるようにソースを修正してもらえるとより回答が得やすいと思います。

Comment: F12でエラーが発生していたようには見えますが、今のでは確認できないでしょうか。確かにスニペットのErrorの返りはScript errorになってはいますが。。。

Comment: ソースを確認したところ、`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gigaplus.makeshop.jp/kukunochi/velocity/script.js"></script>`が存在することで意図しないエラーが発生していたようです。こちらは２重で呼び出されることになるので削除編集しておきました。きちんとスニペットを記述すればエラーも再現性が取れるようになりますのでご注意願います。

Comment: 編集ありがとうございます。削除頂いた部分ですが二重には呼び出ししていなかったと思っていました。削除いただいたscriptのvelocity/script.jsでエラーが起きていると思っていたのですが。。。すごく初歩的な話で恐縮ですが一度目の読み込みの場所はどこになりますか？

Comment: スニペットの機能としてjavascriptパレットでコードを記述するとスニペット側で自動で読み込んでくれます。そのためjavascriptパレットに記述したコードは外部呼び出しする必要ありません。[テスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/)もできますので試してみてください。

Comment: 理解しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。javascriptパレットを用意した場合は自動で読んでくれるんですね。先ほど削除した部分がなくても読み込んでいると言うことですね。ところで、今、起きてるエラーをf12で確認したところjsファイルにコードが書かれていないのですが、何か問題はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくですが、HTTPS通信のブラウザで接続しているのに読み込んでいるリソースがHTTPだから読み込みがブラウザでできなくなっているようです。

> http://julian.com/research/velocity/

このURLはCDNではなくて、サイトから持ってきているようで、HTTPしか受け付けられないようです。

きちんとCDNが公開されているようなのでそちらを利用されるか
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/velocity

ダウンロードしてローカルにて利用するようにしてください。

追記
scriptタグをきちんと記述すれば該当のエラーは出なくなりました。
別のエラーが出ていますが、これはvelocityJSの使い方が間違っていそうです。
公式ドキュメントを確認して修正する必要があるでしょう。

追記2
よく見たらjqueryが2つインストールされていますね。
1.12の方は削除しました。

```js
$(function(){
 $('.open-overlay').click(function() {
   $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
   var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
     top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
     middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
     bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

   overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
   if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

     top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
     overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn', {
       duration: 300,
       delay: 0,
       begin: function() {
         $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveLeftIn', {
           stagger: 150,
           delay: 0,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [1, 0],
             }, {
               delay: 10,
               duration: 140
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         })
       }
     })

   } else {
     $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'none');
     top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
     middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
     bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
     overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
     $('nav ul li').velocity('transition.perspectiveRightOut', {
       stagger: 150,
       delay: 0,
       complete: function() {
         overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.fadeOut', {
           delay: 0,
           duration: 300,
           complete: function() {
             $('nav ul li a').velocity({
               opacity: [0, 1],
             }, {
               delay: 0,
               duration: 50
             });
             $('.open-overlay').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
           }
         });
       }
     })
   }
 })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://gigaplus.makeshop.jp/kukunochi/velocity/style.css">

<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  <div class="open-overlay">
<span class="bar-top"></span>
<span class="bar-middle"></span>
<span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。```<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"　src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.6/velocity.ui.js"></script>```を追加して実行してみましたがダメでした。

Comment: 何がだめでしたか？同じエラーが出てしまっているもしくは違うエラーがでているなど情報をいただけると幸いです。また追加ではなくで、書き換えてください。

Comment: jsファイル ```overlay_navigation.velocity('transition.slideLeftIn', {```の部分で```user-1-1-2-903f893521d3e11ab71d5b08cabb1bdc.js?ptk=417d1de35df8424dd90664659c53bdc005f66a6b&5ee86902500d5:91 Uncaught TypeError: overlay_navigation.velocity is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (user-1-1-2-903f893521d3e11ab71d5b08cabb1bdc.js?ptk=417d1de35df8424dd90664659c53bdc005f66a6b&5ee86902500d5:91)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)```が発生してます。

Comment: スニペットを編集しました。

Comment: 回答にスニペットを追加しました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かにscriptをタグを修正して該当のエラーは出ないですね。velocityJSの使い方が間違っていそうです。と言うお話だったのですが、実はローカル環境で実行しているのですがそこではきちんと動作しております。もちろん、jsファイルの内容は変更していないです。

Comment: であれば問題なさそうですね。

Comment: ですが、サーバで実行するとkeitaro_soさんが回答していただいたスニペットのエラーが出てきてしまっています。。。

Comment: そちらに関しては別の原因の可能性が高いので、一旦こちらの回答は完了してしまって、調査の結果わからなければ新たに質問してもらったほうが良さそうですね。